# Convert the _WTSClient struct from C++ to C#

Tags: c#, c++, struct

I have been trying to convert this struct to C# for the last couple of days, but to no avail...
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb736369(v=vs.85).aspx

```
typedef struct _WTSCLIENT {
  TCHAR  ClientName[CLIENTNAME_LENGTH + 1];
  TCHAR  Domain[DOMAIN_LENGTH + 1 ];
  TCHAR  UserName[USERNAME_LENGTH + 1];
  TCHAR  WorkDirectory[MAX_PATH + 1];
  TCHAR  InitialProgram[MAX_PATH + 1];
  BYTE   EncryptionLevel;
  ULONG  ClientAddressFamily;
  USHORT ClientAddress[CLIENTADDRESS_LENGTH + 1];
  USHORT HRes;
  USHORT VRes;
  USHORT ColorDepth;
  TCHAR  ClientDirectory[MAX_PATH + 1];
  ULONG  ClientBuildNumber;
  ULONG  ClientHardwareId;
  USHORT ClientProductId;
  USHORT OutBufCountHost;
  USHORT OutBufCountClient;
  USHORT OutBufLength;
  TCHAR  DeviceId[MAX_PATH + 1];
} WTSCLIENT, *PWTSCLIENT;
```

This is my attempt so far:

```
[StructLayout( LayoutKind.Sequential )]
public struct _WTSCLIENT {

    [MarshalAs( UnmanagedType.LPTStr )]
    public String ClientName;

    [MarshalAs( UnmanagedType.LPTStr )]
    public String Domain;

    [MarshalAs( UnmanagedType.LPTStr )]
    public String UserName;

    [MarshalAs( UnmanagedType.LPTStr )]
    public String WorkDirectory;

    [MarshalAs( UnmanagedType.LPTStr )]
    public String InitialProgram;

    public Byte EncryptionLevel;

    public uint ClientAddressFamily;

    [MarshalAsAttribute( UnmanagedType.ByValArray)]
    public byte[] ClientAddress;

    public ushort HRes;

    public ushort VRes;

    public ushort ColorDepth;

    [MarshalAs( UnmanagedType.LPTStr )]
    public String ClientDirectory;

    public uint ClientBuildNumber;

    public uint ClientHardwareId;

    public ushort ClientProductId;

    public ushort OutBufCountHost;

    public ushort OutBufCountClient;

    public ushort OutBufLength;

    [MarshalAs( UnmanagedType.LPTStr )]
    public String DeviceId;
}
```

I use it like this:

```
WTSQuerySessionInformation( serverHandle, si.SessionID, WTS_INFO_CLASS.WTSClientInfo, out clientInfoPtr, out bytes );

clientInfo = (_WTSCLIENT)Marshal.PtrToStructure( clientInfoPtr, typeof( _WTSCLIENT ) );
```

...but it bombs out silently, so obviously I have not matched the structure...

Can anyone help me with the struct conversion to C#

TIA...

--

### Dag.

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct WTSCLIENT
{
    private const int CLIENTNAME_LENGTH = 20;
    private const int DOMAIN_LENGTH = 17;
    private const int USERNAME_LENGTH = 20;
    private const int MAX_PATH = 260;
    private const int CLIENTADDRESS_LENGTH = 30;

    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = CLIENTNAME_LENGTH + 1)]
    public string ClientName;

    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = DOMAIN_LENGTH + 1)]
    public string Domain;

    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = USERNAME_LENGTH + 1)]
    public string UserName;

    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = MAX_PATH + 1)]
    public string WorkDirectory;

    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = MAX_PATH + 1)]
    public string InitialProgram;
    public byte EncryptionLevel;
    public uint ClientAddressFamily;

    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = CLIENTADDRESS_LENGTH + 1)]
    public ushort[] ClientAddress;
    public ushort HRes;
    public ushort VRes;
    public ushort ColorDepth;

    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = MAX_PATH + 1)]
    public string ClientDirectory;
    public uint ClientBuildNumber;
    public uint ClientHardwareId;
    public ushort ClientProductId;
    public ushort OutBufCountHost;
    public ushort OutBufCountClient;
    public ushort OutBufLength;

    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = MAX_PATH + 1)]
    public string DeviceId;
}
```

It should work. Its `Marshal.SizeOf` is the "right" one, both at 32 and 64 bits, both Ansi and Unicode.

If you are using the Unicode version of the methods change the first line to:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try the [P/Invoke Interop Assistant](http://clrinterop.codeplex.com/releases/view/14120)

Answer (score 0):

For your   `ULONG  ClientBuildNumber;` and all other `ULONG` s in C++, you have used the C# type `uint`. It could be an error that your definition of `ULONG` is a different size than `uint`.

Maybe you can try using `ulong` in C# (unsigned 64-bit, 0 to 18,446,744,073,709,551,615). This should match the standard Microsoft C++ `ULONG` definition.

[MSDN C++](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s3f49ktz.aspx)

[MSDN C# ulong](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-DE/library/t98873t4.aspx)